# like operator with NSpredicate

Tags: iphone

I have implemented search functionality on my app. but some problem is coming. Please give some suggestion.

Suppose in my Db save on record with name - senior iphone developer.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"( name  contains[cd] %@) ", @"senior "];  // **it work**

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"( name  contains[cd] %@) ", @"senior iphone developer"];  // **it work**

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"( name  contains[cd] %@) ", @"senior developer"];  // **it doesnt work**
```

Have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like[cd] %@", @"senior*developer"];
```